# how to skip certain 0 from date

Tags: php, date, str-replace

My date values look like this: `2021-10-09`

I want to change the format to this: `9/10` ( skip year, skip `0` before the number and change `-` into `/`

```
$date = strtotime('2021-10-09');
$new_date = date('d-m', $date);
$new_date = str_replace('-','/',$new_date);
$new_date = str_replace('0','',$new_date);
echo $new_date // result: 9/1 (should be 9/10)
```

So i need to find a way: if the `0` is behind another number, then DO NOT skip the `0`

How can i do that?

Comment: You are completely over-complicating this. Make good use of the [date formats for PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use date('j/n', $date) and remove str_replace lines.

Comment: Indeed, didn't think about that option. Works great. thnx

Comment: As @aynber says in comment under question, see the [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/datetime.format.php)